# Pass two dimensional javascript array to Controller Action via GET request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm processing some client data in a js function, and I need to pass the variable to a controller action. This is my function:

```
function Save() {
        var matrixIds = [];

        //Do something

        //Then create the URL and pass the parameter
        document.location = "ConciliacionItem/DetallesConciliacionManual/" + $.param({ matriz : matrixIds });
```

So far I've tried with several methods but I can't get to the Controller Action. The only thing that did work was to use an Ajax call like this one:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: myUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                matriz: matrixIds
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });
    }, 500);
```

If i do this, I have the following problem: I need to process the data sent from this view, and the result goes to another view, like this:

```
public ActionResult DetallesConciliacionManual(int[][] matriz)
    {
        //Variable to process
        List<ConciliacionItem> listasAConciliar = new List<ConciliacionItem>();

        //Do a lot of things

        return View(listasAConciliar);
    }
```

So, what I need to do is to be able to pass the js variable of my function to this action, to continue with the app workflow. Is it possible in any way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $.ajax({ type: "POST", should it not be "Get" according to your question?

Comment: Maybe. Doesn't matter though, using ajax forces me to change everything in the Action, and still doing that I couldn't find a way to pass variables to the next view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by manual creating of query string:

```
function Save() {
    var matrixIds = [];

    //Do something

    //Then create the URL and pass the parameter
    document.location = "ConciliacionItem/DetallesConciliacionManual?" + createQueryString('matriz', matrixIds);
}

function createQueryString(sendName, items)
{
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < items[i].length; j++) {
            result += sendName + '[' + i + '][' + j + ']=' + items[i][j] + '&';
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

So you will get a string like

```
matriz[0][0]=0&matriz[0][1]=1&...
```

which will be successfully parsed into two dimensional int array for you action

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. Last night I was able to solve this using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may still use your ajax approach, then after processing your data, you may want to do:

```
public ActionResult DetallesConciliacionManual(int[][] matriz)
{
    //Variable to process
    List<ConciliacionItem> listasAConciliar = new List<ConciliacionItem>();

    //Do a lot of things

    //Returns another view.
    return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
}
```

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx)